# How can an ensemble be more accurate than the best base classifier in that ensemble?

Tags: ensemble-learning

**BACKGROUND:**  Ensemble classifiers are said to reduce *bias* by taking an "average" of predictions of several base classifiers that comprise the ensemble.  However, I am uncertain if this necessarily means that they can increase *accuracy*.  My intuition tells me that the ensemble classifier should perform **no better and possibly even worse** than the *best* base classifier in the ensemble.  This seems especially true for bagging approaches which use strong classifiers anyway.  When you have a "star performer", it just doesn't seem to make intuitive sense to "dilute" its performance with subpar performers.

Nonetheless, from my novice-level reading, it seems that ensembles can be **as good or possibly even better** than all of the individual base classifiers, but I'm still not clear why.

**QUESTION:**  How can an ensemble be more accurate than the best base classifier in that ensemble?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Lets consider binary classification.

Imagine you have an ensemble made up of $K$ models. Assume each model has exactly $51\%$ accuracy. Further assume each model's error is uncorrelated with each other model. The ensemble simply takes a majority vote.

For $K = 11$, what is the probability we get a single question right?
Note: This problem can be simply modeled as flipping an unfair coin $K$ times and calculating the probability that one side will be the majority of flips.

> $P(correct\ \geq\ 6)\ =\ \sum_{k=6}^{11}{\binom{11}{k}({0.51}^k)({0.49}^{11-k})= 0.53}$

What about when $K = 101$?

> $P(correct\ \geq\ 51)\ =\ \sum_{k=51}^{101}{\binom{101}{k}({0.51}^k)({0.49}^{101-k})= 0.58}$

If you do the math you will find that as $K$ approaches $\infty$, the odds of the ensemble being correct asymptotically approaches $100\%$.

> $\lim_{K\rightarrow\infty}{P\left(correct\ \geq\frac{K+1}{2}\right)}={lim}_{K\rightarrow\infty}\left(\sum_{k=\frac{K+1}{2}}^{K}{\binom{K}{k}({0.51}^k)({0.49}^{K-k}})\right)=1$

Now, we made 2 key assumptions:

1. Errors are uncorreleated between models
2. Each model has more than $50\%$ accuracy

In practice these assumptions often may not hold, especially the first one. But if they do, this simple probability analysis shows ensembles will be better

Comment: Note that your models having more than 50% accuracy is a very weak assumption because any model that does worse than random can be used to construct a model that does better than random.

Comment: @OscarSmith, can you explain how that is possible, maybe along with a concrete example?

Comment: you take the model and make a new model that predicts the opposite. (for the n way version it's a bit harder, but you can make a model that chooses a random model other than the one your original model produced)

Comment: Sorry, I may have missed something here.  Is it implied somewhere in the first comment (Note that your models having more than 50% accuracy is a very weak assumption because any model that does worse than random can be used to construct a model that does better than random.) that it is referring to a multiclass situation?

Comment: The generalization of the 50% accuracy condition (which is better than random) is the weak assumption.